# PHP Can't find file

Tags: php, mysql, database

Problem 1:
I got this code

```
<?php
$count_my_page = ("adminpanel/hitcounter.txt");
$hits = file($count_my_page);
$hits[0] ++;
$fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Its in a file called `/beta/` but i need it to find the folder `/adminpanel/` i tried using `/../` and `//` it did not work. I created the error reporting file and this is the output:

```
Warning: file(//adminpanel/hitcounter.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/index.php on line 3

Warning: fopen(//adminpanel/hitcounter.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/index.php on line 5

Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/index.php on line 6

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u463251352/public_html/beta/index.php on line 7
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: use absolute path to get file in php script.

Comment: you're mixing web urls with filesystem paths. PHP itself has absolutely **NO** knowledge of what your site's document root is, nor should it care. You have to use `file('/your/site/document/root/beta/...')`

Comment: Use `../adminpanel/hitcounter.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/adminpanel/hitcounter.txt';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an absolute path based on [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

For 5.3.0 or higher, you can use:

```
__DIR__
```

For PHP lower than 5.3.0, use:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Example:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/dir/file.txt';
```

Will take:

- Root

  - dir

    - file.txt